# Python function should print out something, does nothing

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I wrote small script for my Raspberry Pi Project with an Adafruit 16x2 RGB LCD:

```
def KismetScanner():
print 'Kismet Scan'
#clearlogs = subprocess.Popen('rm -r /var/log/kismet; mkdir /var/log/kismet', shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
monitormode = subprocess.Popen('service ifplugd stop; ifconfig wlan0 down; iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor; ifconfig wlan0 up', shell=True)
lcd.clear()
lcd.backlight(lcd.YELLOW)
lcd.message("Enabled\nMonitor Mode")
sleep(2)
lcd.clear()
lcd.message("Scanning for\nAccessPoints 60s")
kismetscan = subprocess.Popen('kismet&', shell=True)
sleep(60)
grep1essid = subprocess.Popen('grep -oP "SSID.*>\K.*(?=<)" /var/log/kismet/Kismet-Feb-28-2015-1.xml | sed -n 1p', shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
grep1aOut, grep1aErr = grep1essid.communicate()
grep1bssid = subprocess.Popen('grep -oP "SSID.*>\K.*(?=<)" /var/log/kismet/Kismet-Feb-28-2015-1.xml | sed -n 2p', shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
grep1bOut, grep1bErr = grep1bssid.communicate()
print grep1aOut
print grep1bOut
lcd.clear()
lcd.backlight(lcd.GREEN)
lcd.message(grep1aOut + '\n' + grep1bOut)
monitormodeoff = subprocess.Popen('ifconfig wlan0 down; iwconfig wlan0 mode managed; ifconfig wlan0 up; service ifplugd start', shell=True)
sleep(2)
```

The script runs a Kismet Scan and extract the first found SSID and BSSID and shuould print those on the LCD.
The Problem is after it should stored the SSID and BSSID in grep1aOut and grep1bOut it prints the right output, but doesn't display it on the LCD. Only the SSID, so the first line shows up, and I don't understand why.

So where is the mistake ?

Comment: In your code  `stderr=PIPE` should be changed to `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` etc. That may be the error

Comment: That changes a bit, now there is one part of grep1aOut displayed but grepp1bOut still isn't there.

Comment: Strange, your code for SSID and BSSID is identical, isn't it.   Another comment: you execute the kismetscan subprocess, but then you just plain `sleep(60)`. That is suboptimal, you should replace that with `kismetscan.communicate()`. (Although at the moment you are not using the piped output of kismet at all, why not just remove the stderr/out parameters in that call, and use `kismetscan.wait()`. (see the Popen documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait )

Comment: @Ariel where was it identical ? I changed it a bit but still doesn't work.

Comment: By 'identical' I didn't meant letter for letter, but the way it works, so i found strange that one of grep1aOut/grep1bOut contains some value and the other is empty. But now i seem to understand that that part works fine and both variables get the expected value right?

Comment: @Ariel Yes they get the right value now. But now the main problem is that the second line isn't displayed on the lcd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would bet that the `grep*Out` variables contain a trailing newline, because they are the stderr/stdout of Popen... that would explain it because the display only prints two lines. Try this:

```
msg = grep1aOut.strip() + '\n' + grep1bOut.strip()
lcd.message(msg)
```

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you very much :)